# combine four bytes and convert to float

Tags: python, byte, pack, unpack

I found many other threads on my question, but none quite matched what I wanted, or I had difficulty repurposing.

I am using a function called smbus.read_byte().  according to the doc it returns a long.  If I print what it returns, I get a number from 0 to 255.

What I want to do is perform four reads, and then combine that information to generate a float.  So 65, 203, 96, 66 should give 25.422.

There were lots of recommendations of using the struct package, but I'm a bit confused about how to combine the results into one number and then convert that to a float.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> data = [65, 203, 96, 66]
>>> b = ''.join(chr(i) for i in data)
>>> import struct
>>> struct.unpack('>f', b)
(25.422000885009766,)
```

Breaking it down, the `join` line converts each integer value into a character byte then joins them together into a single string, which is what `struct.unpack` requires as input. Testing showed that your bytes were in big-endian order, requiring the `>` in the format to `unpack`.

Python 3 makes a distinction between character strings and byte strings, so the `join` shown above won't work. You can use `struct` instead of `join` to combine the values into a byte string, which works in both Python 2 and 3:

```
b = struct.pack('4B', *data)
```

And now that all versions of Python 2 are officially unsupported, perhaps you don't care about backwards compatibility.  In Python 3 you can convert a list to `bytes` directly without having to convert to `chr` first or use the `struct` module.

```
>>> data = [65, 203, 96, 66]
>>> b = bytes(data)
>>> import struct
>>> struct.unpack('>f', b)
(25.422000885009766,)
```